# Facebook graph api obtaining newsfeed data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph

Hello anyone know how to get the newsfeed data from facebook graph api.Newsfeed as in not the timeline but me/home which is the actual newsfeed in home tab of the facebook .

Comment: There is no API to get newsfeed

Comment: Well, there are other questions stating that they are able to get the newsfeed data and not able to process the large JSON data they obtained from FB graph api

Comment: They are probably old for when it was possible. What is possible is listed at https://developers.facebook.com/docs .